# Are 7 and 49 coprime?

Tags: prime-numbers

Or 6 and 36, 5 and 30, and things like that. They aren't, right? A co prime is a pair of numbers whose greatest common factor is 1. They (7 and 49) share 7 as well as 1. If 7 and 49 aren't co prime, it will clear up a huge programming question.

Comment: They are not coprime. Their greatest common divisor is $7$, not $1$.

Answer (score 2):

Nope they are not. $7$ is a common divisor!

Comment: Thanks. :) (random stuff because comment isn't long enough)

Comment: @Ben You could always put "{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}" in dollar signs (they dont display anything)

Comment: @Ben: better than "Thanks": accept the answer.

Comment: @VladimirLenin you just made it click to me why on the mobile app I saw a lot of people put those after comments... I forgot about the minimum character length!